# Android make a view transparent, or at least semi transparent

Tags: java, android

I'm using the [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). I'm trying to make one of the views semi-transparent. So that you can see what's under it. So its basically a LinearLayout which moves, but I can't see whats underneath.

I've tried setting the `alpha`, the background color (with alpha)

xml settings:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

as well as:

```
android:background="#22000000"
```

I've also tried programmatically:

```
view.setAlpha((float) 0.45));
```

The thing is everything I do doesn't make it transparent. I can see the colours change but its still fully opaque.

Perhaps i've missed something? How can I make it transparent so I can see whats underneath

Answer (score 4):

Use android:alpha="0.1" to set opacity of a layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.2"
    android:background="#000000"
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)

Answer (score 3):

In XML set Background attribute to any colour White(#FFFFFF) shade or Black(#000000) shade.if you want transparancy just put 80 before the actual hash code.

```
#80000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `slidingpanel:overlay="true"` to `SlidingUpPanelLayout`, and then use the color on the transparent view as you decribed (`android:background="@android:color/transparent"` or whatever level of transparency you want).

Answer (score 0):

try to refer it to drawable shape as bellow :

android:background="@drawable/transparant_layout"

**transparant_layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid android:color="#00000000" /> 
 </shape>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I can see the colour change of the linearlayout, but I still can't see anything behind it (no opacity change)

Answer (score 0):

The color hex code is built like this. #ARGB or for a more fine grained control #AARRGGBB which means AlphaRedGreenBlue. Try some colour range for the transparency . the problem is with your hex code for color

Comment: The one I used above is just one, I tried a whole range of different colours such as #00ffffff & #80000000. I can see the colour of the linear layout change, but its still not transparent.

Comment: what is yourbackground color?

Comment: I don't have one, i'm not particularly looking for any background colour, I just want the semi/transparency

Comment: The hash code still just changes the colour to something greyish, but its still solid.